# Explicitly defaulted move constructor makes the struct not trivially copyable

Tags: c++, constructor, default, move

When I declare a basic struct like this in Visual Studio 2019:

```
struct Test
{
    Test(Test &&test) = default;
};
```

the following assert fails :

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Test>::value, "Test is not trivially copyable !");
```

this one:

```
struct Test
{
    Test(const Test &test) = default;
};
```

or this one :

```
struct Test
{

};
```

obviously work. But I really don't understand what is happening with the first one. What is the difference between this one and the others in term of copying behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30097049/560648

Comment: "*What is the difference between this one and the others?*" I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here. The difference is that one is a copy constructor and the other is a move constructor. Are you asking why they behave so significantly differently?

Comment: Yes i want to know why the static_assert testing if the struct is trivially copyable works for the second and third struct, but not the first one. Because they all are trivially copyable for me

Comment: Please analyze my question deeper instead of providing those answers. I want an explanation as to why the first one is not trivially copyable.

Comment: And what version of C++/compiler are you using? That can affect the answer, as the rules of Trivial Copyability have changed over time.

Comment: @Romain227: Then put that in the question, please.

Comment: Seems to be a bug of VS. Can't reproduce with [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rd8k9g0foWWk6Ld1) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3FcxwUGoVAw7u8ZG).

Comment: @Lightness : "A trivially copyable class is a class that: has no non-trivial copy constructors, has no non-trivial move constructors, has no non-trivial copy assignment operators, has no non-trivial move assignment operators, and has a trivial destructor.". I think my first struct completely satisfies this

Comment: @songyuanao : ok so it definitely seems like a VS bug indeed. Very strange though (and kinda scary tbh)

Comment: @Romain227: It actually doesn't satisfy that constraint, but the [*actual* constraint is different](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Visual Studio for modern versions of C++, but it technically *isn't* a bug for the original release of C++11.

First, when I refer to `Test`, I am talking about your first definition. So that we're clear.

By explicitly defaulting `Test`'s move constructor, you have caused the compiler to *implicitly `delete`* the copy constructor and assignment operator, unless you explicitly specify otherwise. The thinking behind this rule is that, if you went out of your way to explicitly `default` a constructor, you are probably trying to say something with that.

A type with only a defaulted move constructor *looks* like a move-only type, so the standard assumes that this is what you want. And if you don't want that, then you need to spell it out.

This doesn't happen for the copy constructor because move is considered a specialized form of copy. If a type is default copyable, it is logically default moveable, so leaving the move constructor implicitly defaulted makes sense.

Things like this are why you shouldn't `default` a special member function unless you either know how that will affect the others or you intend to `default/delete`/implement all of them.

In the initial release of C++11, the implicit deletion of copying for a defaulted move constructor would have made `Test` non-TriviallyCopyable. However, the wording for Trivial Copyability was changed around C++14 [via a defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1734). The new wording allowed a type to be TriviallyCopyable even if some of the copy/move constructors/assignment operators are deleted. Thus making `Test` TriviallyCopyable. Defect fixes usually apply retroactively, so technically a modern C++11 implementation should work too.

Visual Studio was never changed to fit the new wording. Hence the bug.

Comment: "By explicitly defaulting Test's move constructor, you have caused the compiler to implicitly delete the copy constructor and assignment operator, unless you explicitly specify otherwise". Adding a defaulted copy construtor in addition to the defaulted move constructor still makes the assertion fail.

Comment: @Romain227: I said, and you even copied me, "and assignment operator". Or more specifically, "Things like this are why you shouldn't default a special member function unless you either know how that will affect the others or you intend to default/delete/implement all of them."